# How to Loop Through Elements Ending with a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have a form with five input statements with the id ending with a sequential number like:

```
<input id="phone1" type="text" value="1111111111">
<input id="phone2" type="text" value="">
<input id="phone3" type="text" value="3333333333">
<input id="phone4" type="text" value="4444444444">
<input id="phone5" type="text" value="">
```

I attempted the following:

```
const nmbr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$.each(nmbr, function(index, value){
  var phn = $("#phone"+value)
  if !(phn.val()) {
     console.log('phone number missing');
   }
});
```

How would I step through these id's to get the value of the non-blank phone numbers.

Comment: Why not just give them a common class? Or use a starts with selector `$('[id^="phone"]').each()` Or just use HTML5 validation with required attribute

Comment: Why don't you just put a same class and get the id and value of the field through that class. for example: put a class="a" in all fields and then 
$('.a').each(function () {
            var ChkBxMsgId;
            ChkBxMsgId = $(this).attr('id');//this is your id if you want to use it
            ChkBxMsgvalue = $(this).attr('value');//this is the value of each field
            alert(ChkBxMsgvalue);
        });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a class instead and then loop through the `input` and check if value is non empty

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.ipt');

for (const ipt of inputs) {
  if (ipt.value !== "") {
    console.log(ipt.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="ipt" id="phone1" type="text" value="1111111111">
<input class="ipt" id="phone2" type="text" value="">
<input class="ipt" id="phone3" type="text" value="3333333333">
<input class="ipt" id="phone4" type="text" value="4444444444">
<input class="ipt" id="phone5" type="text" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

In Below Code **document.querySelectorAll('[id^="phone"]')** will **select all the ids with phone prefix**.

```js
    const data =  document.querySelectorAll('[id^="phone"]');
    console.log(data);
    
    
    for (const dt of data) {
      if (dt.value !== "") {
        console.log(dt.value);
      }
    }
```

```html
    <input id="phone1" type="text" value="1111111111">
    <input id="phone2" type="text" value="">
    <input id="phone3" type="text" value="3333333333">
    <input id="phone4" type="text" value="4444444444">
    <input id="phone5" type="text" value="">
```